# What's the proper response to "Wann arbeitest du?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Wann arbeitest du?

"Wann" here is asking for a specific point of time I think.
So if I answer, "Ich arbeite von Montag bis Freitag", it's like a period of time.

Will it be wrong or should I even say: *"Ich arbeite um zehn Uhr?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both alternatives are correct, therefore it depends on the context.

Often the question is asked more concretely:

> Von wann bis wann arbeitest du? (during the day) [period of time]

> Wann fängst du an zu arbeiten? (during the day, at all) [specific point of time]

> Wann arbeitest du? (If an appointment is to be planned (When do you have time?)) [not clearly specified]

> ...

I think that the question is pointing to the beginning of your shift, but without any context it's nothing else than a good gess.

Answer (score 1):

Even if "*Wann*" normally asks about a point in time, in the context of working
I would expect that the question

> *Wann arbeitest du?*

must ask about some *time range or duration*, because you normally work for some considerable duration, not only at a specific point in time.

Of course this would be clearer with

> *Von wann bis wann arbeitest Du?*

or

> *Zu welchen Zeiten arbeitest Du?*

and many more variations of the question

---

Without context it is difficult to know what answer exatly is expected.

Depending on the context, the expected answer could be the regular time range when you work every day or on which days of the week you (normally) work. Or it might be about a specific situation like this week, next week, a specific day...

The context of the question might be to find out when you are available at your work place (e.g. for a meeting/appointment) or when you you might be available in your spare time.

---

I consider the answer

> *Ich arbeite um zehn Uhr.*

as strange and would merely expect something like

> *Ich arbeite **ab** zehn Uhr*.

or

> *Ich arbeite von zehn bis sechs.*

Comment: Thank you, Ich arbeite von zehn bis sechs feels good.